# Can I use 2 API keys to validate a single API gateway API?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I know of a way to have a single API key for authorization purposes of API gateway. Can I have "AND" behavior of 2 API keys as the authorization part of the API gateway API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented a little and figured out that API gateway doesn't provide any such support out of box but there is a way to provide the '-' separated or by any other special character separated API key.

There is a way to add the custom API key. So you can concatenate 2 keys yourself and set it as another API key.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple API keys are not supported, but you can a third API key to represent APIkey1 AND APIkey2 kind of behavior.